# How do I call a function in a class with a variable?

Tags: python, class

This is an example of a part of my larger code segment, and I've been having trouble with this part.

```
class test:

  def __init__(self, test):
    self.test = test

  def tester(self):
    print("This should print")


variable = test("information")

issue = "variable"

issue.tester()
```

Is there any way I can call tester using a variable?

Comment: This has nothing to do with classes. You're just asking how to get a variable from a string.

Comment: You mean like `def tester(self, issue):` and then call `variable.tester(issue)`?

Comment: @jarmod He's just trying to do dynamic variables.

Comment: `variable.tester()` uses a variable.

Comment: Grim. In that case, use  dict e.g. `vardict = {}`, `vardict[issue] = test("information")` and `vardict[issue].tester()`

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I'm new to this website (and coding) as you can probably tell. But Im trying to get "This should print" to print with just a variable. Also Im trying to print this statement without doing variable.tester() .

Comment: `variable` is a variable. Why isn't `variable.tester()` calling the function with a variable?

Comment: If you want a dynamic variable, read the duplicate question I linked to at the top.

Comment: The basic answer is that you shouldn't try to do dynamic variables. You should use a dictionary instead.